# How can I remove repeated lines taking into consideration the text from just a column?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the following file:

```
ICR1 +
ICR1+1+3199 +
ICR1+2526+2828 +
IRT1 +
IRT1+1+1489 +
IRT1+713+937 +
LSR1 -
LSR1+1+1175 -
LSR1+366+638 -
NME1 +
NME1+1+340 +
NME1+2+118 +
PWR1 -
PWR1+1+941 -
PWR1+724+939 -
Q0017 -
Q0017+1+162 -
Q0020 -
Q0020+1370+1513 -
Q0020+1+440 -
```

The first and second columns are tab-separated. I do need to have the following:

```
ICR1 +
IRT1 +
LSR1 -
NME1 +
PWR1 -
Q0017 -
Q0020 -
```

I've tried to use awk with the field separator "+" but it erased the + from the second column as well...

Comment: Is your file really structured like that? So on the last line, no tabs around the `+`?

Comment: Yes, it's structured like that, there are no tabs after the second column. The first column may be "Name" or "Name+Number" or "Name+Number+Number"

Comment: you want the lines only with "Name" not "Name+something.." ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set awk's field separator to whitespace or `+`, and then do the classic associative array based de-duplication:

```
$ awk -F'[ \t+]' '!seen[$1]++' file
ICR1 +
IRT1 +
LSR1 -
NME1 +
PWR1 -
Q0017 -
Q0020 -
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know I could do that! Now it'll make my life easier on other similar files as well

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved same by using `sed` command

```
sed -n '/^.\{1,5\} .$/p' filename
```

output

```
ICR1 +
IRT1 +
LSR1 -
NME1 +
PWR1 -
Q0017 -
Q0020 -
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller):

```
mlr --tsv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output \
    put -S '$1=gsub($1,"[+].+$","")' then uniq -a inputfile
```

and the output is:

```
ICR1    +
IRT1    +
LSR1    -
NME1    +
PWR1    -
Q0017   -
Q0020   -
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I've misunderstood the problem, but this seems to work:

```
grep -v '+.' file
```

Output:

```
ICR1 +
IRT1 +
LSR1 -
NME1 +
PWR1 -
Q0017 -
Q0020 -
```